# How to convert a list of lists with separate lists that have the same first element to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to convert a list of lists like so:

```
[['S', 'NP', 'VP'], ['NP', 'Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'NP', 'PP'], ['VP', 'V', 'NP'], ['VP', 'VP', 'PP'], ['PP', 'P', 'NP'], ['Det', "'the'"], ['N', "'pirate'"], ['N', "'sailor'"], ['N', "'telescope'"], ['V', "'sees'"], ['P', "'with'"]]
```

to a dictionary such that it looks like this:

```
{'S':['NP', 'VP'], 'NP': ['Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'PP'], 'VP': ['V', 'NP'], ['VP', 'PP'], 'PP': ['P', 'NP'], 'Det': ["'the'"], 'N': ["'pirate'"], ["'sailor'"], ["'telescope'"], 'V': ["'sees'"], 'P': ["'with'"]}
```

I have tried using this method using `from collections import default dict`:

```
g = defaultdict(dict)
for i, j, k in new_grammar:
    g[i][j] = k
```

But this does not work because there are lists in the list of lists with only two elements.

I have also tried:

```
grammar = {}
for rule in new_grammar:
    grammar[rule[0]] = rule[1:]
```

However, this only gives each key one value.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What you show as the desired dictionary is not, in fact, valid python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track, but your defaultdict is a mapping from a string to list, and not dictionnary. Try this :

```
g = defaultdict(list)
for i in new_grammar:
    g[i[0]].extend(i[1:])
```

Comment: Or possibly use list.append instead of list.extend. It's not really clear what output the asker is looking for, since the example in the question isn't valid python.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way using `collections.defaultdict`.

Note the result is a dictionary with a list of values assigned to each key. This is not how you have defined your desired output, which is not valid Python.

```
L = [['S', 'NP', 'VP'], ['NP', 'Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'NP', 'PP'], ['VP', 'V', 'NP'], ['VP', 'VP', 'PP'], ['PP', 'P', 'NP'], ['Det', "'the'"], ['N', "'pirate'"], ['N', "'sailor'"], ['N', "'telescope'"], ['V', "'sees'"], ['P', "'with'"]]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, *v in L:
    d[k].extend(v)

print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'Det': ["'the'"],
             'N': ["'pirate'", "'sailor'", "'telescope'"],
             'NP': ['Det', 'N', 'NP', 'PP'],
             'P': ["'with'"],
             'PP': ['P', 'NP'],
             'S': ['NP', 'VP'],
             'V': ["'sees'"],
             'VP': ['V', 'NP', 'VP', 'PP']})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this? or is this what you want?:

```
l = [['S', 'NP', 'VP'], ['NP', 'Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'NP', 'PP'], ['VP', 'V', 'NP'], ['VP', 'VP', 'PP'], ['PP', 'P', 'NP'], ['Det', "'the'"], ['N', "'pirate'"], ['N', "'sailor'"], ['N', "'telescope'"], ['V', "'sees'"], ['P', "'with'"]]
print(dict(zip([i[0] for i in l],[i[1:] for i in l])))
```

Output:

```
{'S': ['NP', 'VP'], 'NP': ['NP', 'PP'], 'VP': ['VP', 'PP'], 'PP': ['P', 'NP'], 'Det': ["'the'"], 'N': ["'telescope'"], 'V': ["'sees'"], 'P': ["'with'"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
add to the dictionary if element is not present. Append to dictionary if element is present.

```
l = [['S', 'NP', 'VP'], ['NP', 'Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'NP', 'PP'], ['VP', 'V', 'NP'], ['VP', 'VP', 'PP'], ['PP', 'P', 'NP'], ['Det', "'the'"], ['N', "'pirate'"], ['N', "'sailor'"], ['N', "'telescope'"], ['V', "'sees'"], ['P', "'with'"]]


grammar = {}
for rule in l:
    if(grammar.get(rule[0],None) == None):
        grammar[rule[0]] = rule[1:]
    else:
        for elem in rule[1:]:
            grammar[rule[0]].append(elem)

print grammar
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

L = [['S', 'NP', 'VP'], ['NP', 'Det', 'N'], ['NP', 'NP', 'PP'], ['VP', 'V', 'NP'], ['VP', 'VP', 'PP'], ['PP', 'P', 'NP'], ['Det', "'the'"], ['N', "'pirate'"], ['N', "'sailor'"], ['N', "'telescope'"], ['V', "'sees'"], ['P', "'with'"]]

result = {k: list(chain(*(x[1:] for x in g))) for 
          k, g in groupby(sorted(L, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))}

pprint(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
{'Det': ["'the'"],
 'N': ["'pirate'", "'sailor'", "'telescope'"],
 'NP': ['Det', 'N', 'NP', 'PP'],
 'P': ["'with'"],
 'PP': ['P', 'NP'],
 'S': ['NP', 'VP'],
 'V': ["'sees'"],
 'VP': ['V', 'NP', 'VP', 'PP']}
```